# Animación de JQuery

Tags: jquery, animación

Tengo 4 Elementos en `html` en una columna de todo el ancho y alto del `<div class="container">` , necesito que con `jquery` me anime los 4 elementos, con una animación de entrada de los 4 elementos primero el bienvenido, se desvanece y luego se pone arriba dentro de la columna, luego entra el logo y se traslada a la izquierda, luego viene la firma y este va a la derecha y por último entra el logo de la escuela y va a la derecha despues de la firma, esa es toda la animación. Lo estoy haciendo con **bootstrap 3** y en **wordpress**, y en este **wordpress** tengo *visual composer* con un *theme* desactualizado llamado: **scent** no soporta *guttenberg*, y poseo dos elementos para esa animación el `html` puro y el `js` puro que introducen código dentro del `<body>`, y también tengo la posibilidad de dar un ID o un CLASS a los elementos.

Esto es lo que tengo por el momento:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS LIBRARY-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS LIBRARY-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>Animacion de Entrada Grupo Empresarial SKY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <img src="img/bienvenido.jpg" alt="imagen-bienvenido" id="bienvenido" class="bienvenido-css">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="imagen-logo" id="logo" class="logo-css">
          <img src="img/firma.jpg" alt="imagen-firma" id="firma" class="firma-css">
          <img src="img/escuela.png" alt="imagen-academia" id="escuela" class="escuela-css">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS LIBRARY-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS LIBRARY-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

La hoja de `js`:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
  $(#bienvenido).show();
  $(#bienvenido).animate({top:"+=100px"},2000);
  $(#logo).show();
  $(#logo).animate({ right: "+=100px" }, 2000 );
  $(#firma).show();
  $(#firma).animate({left:"+=100px"},2000);
  $(#escuela).show();
  $(#escuela).animate({left:"+=200px"},2000);
});
```

La hoja de `CSS`:

```
.fondo{background-color: white;}
.logo-css{display:none;z-index:0;width: 260px;height: 260px;}
.firma-css{display: none;z-index:0;}
.escuela-css{display: none;z-index:0;}
.bienvenido-css{display:none;z-index:0;}
```

Eso es todo lo que tengo por el momento actualmente estoy completando por medio de la documentación de `jquery`, `css`, `html`. Solo necesito que me guíen el resto lo hago yo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero, tu código `JQuery` tiene unos pequeños detalles, cuando llamas un elemento por su id, necesitas encerrarlo entre comillas por ejemplo  `$("#bienvenido").show();`, de lo contrario te va a dar error.

Para que la funcion `animate` funcione correctamente, tus elementos `html` necesitan tener la propiedad `position:relative` o `position:absolute`, de lo contrario no podrán animarse.

Por ultimo, para que tus animaciones se ejecuten unas después de otras necesitas anidar las funciones, para que una vez terminada una, ejecute otra.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#bienvenido").show();
  $("#bienvenido").animate({top:"+=100px"},2000, function() {
    $("#logo").show();
   $("#logo").animate({ right: "+=100px" }, 2000, function() {
     $("#firma").show();
       $("#firma").animate({left:"+=100px"},2000, function() {
         $("#escuela").show();
      $("#escuela").animate({left:"+=200px"},2000);
      });
    });
  }); 
});
```

```css
.fondo{background-color: white;}
.logo-css{display:none;z-index:0;width: 260px;height: 260px; position: relative;}
.firma-css{display: none;z-index:0;position: relative;}
.escuela-css{display: none;z-index:0;position: relative;}
.bienvenido-css{display:none;z-index:0;position: relative;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS LIBRARY-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS LIBRARY-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>Animacion de Entrada Grupo Empresarial SKY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <img src="img/bienvenido.jpg" alt="imagen-bienvenido" id="bienvenido" class="bienvenido-css">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="imagen-logo" id="logo" class="logo-css">
          <img src="img/firma.jpg" alt="imagen-firma" id="firma" class="firma-css">
          <img src="img/escuela.png" alt="imagen-academia" id="escuela" class="escuela-css">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS LIBRARY-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS LIBRARY-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero y te de el apoyo que necesitas.

Tengo otra cuestion mejor publico el codigo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS LIBRARY-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS LIBRARY-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>Animacion de Entrada Grupo Empresarial SKY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 tableroEncabezado">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 tableroLogo">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 tableroFirma">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 tableroEscuela">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--IMAGENES
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="imagen-bienvenido" id="bienvenido" class="bienvenido-css">
    <img src="img/2.png" alt="imagen-logo" id="logo" class="logo-css">
    <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="imagen-firma" id="firma" class="firma-css">
    <img src="img/4.png" alt="imagen-academia" id="escuela" class="escuela-css">
    -->
    <!--IMAGENES-->
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS LIBRARY-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS LIBRARY-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

el JS:

```
$(function() {
  //imagenBienvenida();
  animacionPorCeldas();
});

//Animacion con animate
/*function animacion(){
 $("#1").animate({top:"+=100px"},2000, function() {
   $("#2").animate({ right: "+=100px" }, 2000, function() {
       $("#3").animate({left:"+=100px"},2000, function() {
       $("#4").animate({left:"+=200px"},2000);
     });
   });
 });
}*/
//Animacion con animate

function animacionPorCeldas(){
  $(".tableroEncabezado").append("<img src='img/1.jpg' alt='imagen-bienvenido' id='bienvenido' class='bienvenido-css'>").fadeIn();

  //$("#1").fadein("",function(){

  //}).animate({
    //right:"+=400px",
    //height:"300px",
    //width:"300px"
  //},5000);
}

//function imagenBienvenida(){
  //$(".tableroEncabezado").append("<img src='img/1.jpg' alt='imagen-bienvenido' id='bienvenido' class='bienvenido-css'>");
  //$(".tableroLogo").append("<img src='img/2.png' alt='imagen-logo' id='logo' class='logo-css'>");
  //$(".tableroFirma").append("<img src='img/3.jpg' alt='imagen-firma' id='firma' class='firma-css'>");
  //$(".tableroEscuela").append("<img src='img/4.png' alt='imagen-academia' id='escuela' class='escuela-css'>");
//}
```

el css:

```
.fondo{background-color: white;}
.logo-css{width: 260px;height: 260px; position: relative;}
.firma-css{position: relative;width: 260px;height: 260px;}
.escuela-css{position: relative;width: 260px;height: 260px;}
.bienvenido-css{position: relative;}
```

El punto es este como hago para agregar el elemento tableroEncabezado y con un fadeIn?

```
$(".tableroEncabezado").append("<img src='img/1.jpg' alt='imagen-bienvenido' id='bienvenido' class='bienvenido-css'>").fadeIn();
```

Gracias por la aclaracion.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, de inmediato probare el codigo.

Comment: Como hago para poner en una sola columna varios objetos y que no escalen sino que esten uno superpuesto sobre otro.

Comment: Ha que te refieres?, no entiendo.

Comment: Es decir necesito poner varias imagenes en un solo contenedor pero que no se esparcen sino que se agrupen en un solo espacio, y ya despues que se muevan por animacion.

Comment: Perdon pero me toco editar lo que habia puesto como respuesta...cual era la pagina que me habias compartido, esta vez si podre verla de inmediato, estoy laborando.

Comment: Era este https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoPerez/na7Lxbwp/

Comment: La edición que hiciste donde pides tu nuevo cambio va directamente en tu pregunta principal, no en mi respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada amigo, si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como aceptada, para que pueda ayudar a otras personas mas adelante.

Comment: donde puedo dar por aceptado la respuesta?

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas